# How to autoscale Cassandra cluster on AWS or how to node dynamically to the cluster depending upon the load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have been trying to auto-scale a 3node Cassandra cluster with Replication Factor 3 and Consistency Level 1 on Amazon EC2 instances.

What steps do I need to perform to add/remove nodes to the cluser dynamically based on load on application?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately scaling up and down responding to the current load is not straightforward, and if you have a cluster with a large amount of data, this won't be possible:

- you can't add multiple nodes simultaneously to a cluster, all the
  operations need to be sequential.
- adding or removing a node will require to stream data in or out of 
  the node; this will depend on the size of your data, as well as the 
  EC2 instance type you are using (for the network bandwidth limit); 
  also, there will be differences if you are utilizing instance 
  storage or EBS (EBS will limit you in IOPS)
- You mentioned that you are using AWS and a replication factor of 3, 
  are you also using different availability zones (AZ's)? if you are,
  the EC2Snitch will work to ensure that the information is balanced
  between them, in order to be resilient, when you are scaling up and
  down you will need to keep an even distribution between AZ's.
- The scale operations will cause a rearrangement in the distribution 
  of tokens, once that it is completed you will need to do a cleanup 
  (`nodetool cleanup`) to remove data that is not in use anymore by 
  the node; this operation will also take time. This is important to 
  keep in mind if you are scaling up because you are running out 
  space.

For our use case, we are getting good results taking a proactive approach, we have set up an aggressive alert/monitoring strategy to have an early detection, so we can start the scale up operations before there is any performance impact. If your application or use case has a predictable pattern of usage can also help you to take actions in preparation of periods of high workloads.